# Cumulate RunProperties on Run with OpenXML SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, bold, underline

I was wondering if I could cumulate `RunProperties` on `Run`

```
Run run = new Run(new Text("test"));
RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
runProperties.AppendChild<Bold>(new Bold());
runProperties.AppendChild<Underline>(new Underline());
run.AppendChild<RunProperties>(runProperties);
```

In this case, I only got Bold text but not Underline.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your example and indeed it only did bold for me and not underline. I worked it a bit and ended up with this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destFileName, true))
{

    Run run = new Run();
    RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();

    runProperties.AppendChild<Underline>(new Underline() { Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.UnderlineValues.Single });
    runProperties.AppendChild<Bold>(new Bold());
    run.AppendChild<RunProperties>(runProperties);
    run.AppendChild(new Text("test"));

    //Note: I had to create a paragraph element to place the run into.
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.AppendChild(run);
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(p);
}
```

Basically, this changed:

```
new Underline() { Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.UnderlineValues.Single }
```

You have to specify the type of underline you want and not just leave it up to the Underline class's constructor. I just specified `Single` and it worked for me.